# Finding a linear combination base on given vectors that equal to a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading through A First Course in Linear Algebra by Robert Breeze and I'm having a hard time understanding some stuff.

The reading question 2 on page 104 is one of it.

I'm not sure how to solve it.

The question is:

Find a linear combination of the vectors
$$
s = \{ [1,3,-1]^T, [2,0,4]^T, [-1,3,-5]^T\}
$$

that equals to the vector $[1,-9,11]^T$

How I think I should solve it is to set it up like so:
$$
[1,-9,11]^T = X_1[1,3,-1]^T + X_2[2,0,4]^T + X_3[-1,3,-5]^T
$$
But I'm not sure that is correct since the vectors aren't in RREF (Reduced Row Echelon Form). Perhaps I'm missing something and going about it the wrong way?

Perhaps I'm suppose to use this theorem:

> Theorem PSPHS Particular Solution Plus Homogeneous Solutions Suppose
>   that $w$ is one solution to the linear system of equations $LS(A, b)$.
>   Then $y$ is a solution to $LS(A, b)$ if and only if $y = w + z$ for some
>   vector $z ∈ N(A)$.

Unfortunately, I don't understand this theorem well, only how to use it. Can someone explain it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct. Your equation is equivalent to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&-1\\
3&0&3\\
-1&4&-5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end {bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-9\\
11
\end {bmatrix}
$$
that you can solve reducing the matrix or in any other way as a linear system.

The PSPHP simply say that if $\bar x$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ and y is a solution of $Ax=0$ then also $\bar x +y$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ since: 
$$
A(\bar x +y)=A \bar x + Ay = b+0
$$